# Horizontal border using image

Tags: html, border, css

I have [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwG0j.png) that I want to use for `border-bottom` for `.box` class:

```
<div class="box">Hello World</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
    background: #16a085;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "monospace";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

The result is:

> [image: Result]

How can I set an image as border, being repeated horizontally, on the bottom side? A margin between the green background and border line would be required also.

I tried:

```
/* border stuff */
border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwG0j.png);
border-image-repeat: repeat;
```

An alternative without using images would be:

```
border-bottom: 3px dotted #367dd2;
padding-bottom: 4px;
```

...but I want to use an image for border instead.

[**JSFDIDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr5Bg/)

Comment: Try `border-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/CRWpl2d.png') 0% 0% 10% 0% repeat;` where 10% is the size of the bottom border, you can also use number values which will be pixels

Comment: @singe31 I don't see any difference

Comment: can simply do border: 1px solid some color ?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Mr5Bg/7/ ?

Comment: @AlexWilson No, because the image has two parts: one is blue and the other one is transparent. That gives the dotted effect.

Comment: @Bugaloo Yes! But, with more space. :-)

Comment: where do you want more space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set border using `background` property from the bottom side like this:

```
background: #16a085 url('http://i.imgur.com/CRWpl2d.png') bottom center repeat-x;
```

---

But if you want to **use margin between background and border** maybe this fiddle is useful for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/CfT2c/

Comment: Is it possible to remove border for the last element (see: http://jsfiddle.net/CfT2c/1/)?

Comment: Awesome! The best. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your vendor prefixes could be the issue, as well as specifying your border styles as you would normally. Let me know if this helps!

```
border: 15px solid transparent;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 30 30 round; /* Safari */
-o-border-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 30 30 round;
```

Comment: Updated, just specify your widths and set 0 to your border to, left, and right

Answer (score 0):

You can below css3 `border-image` property

```
-webkit-border-image:url(imageURL) 30 30 round; /* for Safari browsers*/
-o-border-image:url(imageURL) 30 30 round;  /* for opera browsers*/
border-image:url(imageURL) 30 30 round;
```

IE 8,9 might not support border-image property, by you can achieve it by css3pie. Please refer http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/